# NSDictionary failed to read array in webservice

Tags: ios, json, xcode, web-services, nsdictionary

I'm newbie in developing Xcode 5 and unable to connect to SQLServer via php.
The php result is this:

```
{"user":[{"user_id":"2393", "id":"740049"}], "succeed":1}
```

This webservice created not by me but my team. I tried to track the process via NSLog and found the problem is NSDictionary i created unable to read this kind of format.

This is my NSDictionary

```
NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:urlData option:NSJONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
success=[json[@"success"] integerValue];
NSLog(@"Success:%ld", (long)success);
```

if my NSDictionary were able to read the data then the success should be 1 but it keep showing 0. I find the problem is that i cant parse that array in dictionary. Could anyone help me fix this thing?

Comment: check your key,u are using different key

Comment: what key? sorry for such a noob question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mistype the key value. it will be @"succeed". But you type @"success"

```
NSJSONSerialization *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: urlData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
int success=[[(NSDictionary *)jsonData valueForKey:@"succeed"]integerValue];
NSLog(@"Success:%ld", (long)success);
```

Answer (score 0):

Typo:

```
success=[json[@"succeed"] integerValue];
//              ^^^^^^^
```

Comment: i tried that before but thats not the problem. Change it to succeed will cause error Thread 1 signal SIGABRT

Comment: @user3932914 That's a different error and needs a question by itself.

Comment: Yes i know the cause of that error. I stumble a thousand times with SIGABRT and become used to fix it. I figured out my problem was my NSDictionary able to only get user and succedd instead of an array inside user array. But i dont know how to fix it

Comment: @user3932914 I can only answer the question presented to me, and this is the only issue I can see in your question.  There is nothing more I can add without more detail, but you won't make any further progress until you start using the correct keys in the dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

```
//returnString is {"user":[{"user_id":"2393", "id":"740049"}], "succeed":1};

NSDictionary *response = [returnString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSArray *users =[NSArray alloc]init];
if([[response valueForKey:@"succeed"] integerValue] == 1)
    users = [response valueForKey:@"user"];
for(NSDictionary *user in users)
    NSLog(@"User : %@", user);
```

**Sample Output**

```
User: [{user_id:2393,id:740049},{user_id:2394,id:740050}...,{user_id:2395,id:740051}];
```